# CastError: Cast to string failed for value (Mongoose, React js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am getting an email from **lstate** which is a state of **useReducer**. I am getting lstate value by using **Context api** and **useContext**. But my **problem** is that i transfered the lstate using fetch api to my backend **auth.js** to get the document of the required email from the MongoDB. But i am not getting email from lstate at backend i am getting objects.

**Account.jsx**

```
const Account = () => {

    const { lstate } = useContext(LoginContext);

    const LoginData = async () => {

        console.log(`my lstate in login function ${lstate}`);  

        await fetch('/account', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                lstate           
             })
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        LoginData();
    }, []);
```

**auth.js**

```
router.post('/account', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        

        const email = req.body;

        console.log(`data from account ${email}`);

        const data = await CustomerModel.findOne({ email: email });

        if (data) {

            return res.json(data);
        }
        
    } catch (error) {
        
        console.log(error);
    }

})
```

**Console Error**

```
data from account [object Object]  
CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ lstate: 'usman4276@gmail.com' }" at path "email" for model "Customer_reg"
    at model.Query.exec (C:\MERN stack\online-cattle-shop\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4408:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (C:\MERN stack\online-cattle-shop\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.jsbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4502:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: `"{ lstate: 'usman4276@gmail.com' }"`,  kind: 'string',
  value: { lstate: 'usman4276@gmail.com' },
  path: 'email',
  reason: null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be

```
const { email } = req.body;
```

OR

```
 const email = req.body.email;
```

You should also add conditional checks.

E.g.

```
if (!email) throw new Error ('Email Required')
```

Comment: this works perfect for me  const email = req.body.lstate;

Answer (score 0):

The code in the client is sending a JSON and the key `lstate` contains the actual mail.

you need to do

```
const email = req.body.email.lstate;

const data = await CustomerModel.findOne({ email });
```